# .NET Core 2.2 return async SendGrid response to ajax

Tags: .net-core, sendgrid

I'm a .NET noob and am using `.NET Core 2.2` and [`sendgrid-csharp`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) NuGet package with `Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition`

I have a form which is sent via an `ajax` call to a controller method which sends an email via `SendGrid`. The email is successfully sent and I can log the response. However, a response is never returned to the `ajax` call and just hangs in the browser until it times out.

I would like to return the `response.StatusCode` of the `SendGrid` response to the `ajax` call.

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;

namespace MyProject.Controllers {
  public class HomeController:Controller {
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SendMessageEmail() {
      using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body)) {
        var formData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        formData["subject"] = "Email Subject";
        formData["body"]    = "Email Body";

        EmailSender emailSenderService = new EmailSender();
        var response = await emailSenderService.Execute(formData["fromemail"], formData["toemail"], formData["subject"], formData["body"], formData["body"]);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine("response: ", response);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");

        return new JsonResult(response.StatusCode);
      }
    }
  }

  internal class EmailSender {
    public async Task<Response> Execute(string From, string To, string subject, string plainTextContent, string htmlContent) {
      var apiKey    = "MY_SEND_GRID_KEY";
      var client    = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
      var from      = new EmailAddress(From);
      var to        = new EmailAddress(To);
      var msg       = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
      var response  = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

**form.js**

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#email-message-form', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  var emailMessageForm  = $('form#email-message-form');
  var messageTo         = $('form#email-message-form #message-to');
  var messageFrom       = $('form#email-message-form #message-from');
  var data              = {};
      data.toemail      = messageTo.val()
      data.fromemail    = messageFrom.val()

  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SendMessageEmail",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false
  }).done(function (msg) {
    console.log('Success: ', msg);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("Send email method failed: " + textStatus);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGH – Apparently I'm an idiot and all I needed to do was to change `async: false` to `async: true` in my `form.js` file.

**UPDATED & WORKING form.js**

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#email-message-form', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  var emailMessageForm  = $('form#email-message-form');
  var messageTo         = $('form#email-message-form #message-to');
  var messageFrom       = $('form#email-message-form #message-from');
  var data              = {};
      data.toemail      = messageTo.val()
      data.fromemail    = messageFrom.val()

  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SendMessageEmail",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: true
  }).done(function (msg) {
    console.log('Success: ', msg);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("Send email method failed: " + textStatus);
  });
});
```